# Text Input Placeholder Overflowing in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

```html
<input
    class="form-control"
    style="width: 15rem; height: 15rem;"
    v-model="formData.booking_code"
    placeholder="Masukkan Kode Booking, contoh : XYBJLL"
/>
```

so, I want to add a placeholder to my input text. but it gets too long so it overflows and the text gets cut off.

I want to make the placeholder text continue to the bottom when it reaches the edge.

I don't want to use a text area, because it can't be vertically aligned

Comment: "Continue to the bottom" -- do you mean split to a new line?  Placeholders can't do that,.  They are a very limited feature.  However, you can put whatever you want in surrounding text, and even use CSS to make it come and go.

Comment: thank you sir, for the information. But what do you mean by putting whatever surrounding the text, and may I ask for a css style example so that it can create a new line

Comment: What I mean is adding a separate `<span>` tag to the right or below your text box containing your prompt text.  You can use Javascript to make that go invisible once they type something.

Comment: What do you mean by, you cant vertically align a text area?

Answer (score 0):

Position a div or span element over the input field. This element will contain the placeholder text and will break into lines as necessary.

```css
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 15rem;
    height: 3rem;
}

.form-control {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    background: transparent;
}

.placeholder {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #aaa; /* Placeholder text color */
    padding: 0.5rem;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap; /* Allows the text to wrap */
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; /* Vertically center */
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input
        class="form-control"
        style="width: 15rem; height: 3rem;"
        v-model="formData.booking_code"
        id="bookingCodeInput"
    />
    <span class="placeholder">Masukkan Kode Booking, contoh: XYBJLL</span>
</div>
```